# Search an array and return related results

Tags: php, arrays

This is a sample of my array

```
$records = 
Array
(
    [attribute_id] => 6703
    [base_product] => 382
)
Array
(
    [attribute_id] => 6704
    [base_product] => 397
)
Array
(
    [attribute_id] => 6705
    [base_product] => 409    
)
Array
(
    [attribute_id] => 6706
    [base_product] => 321
);
```

I need to do this in PHP Version 5.5

I need to search by [attribute_id] and return the [base_product] value.

My site had been down for 4 days now. It looks so simple, I must just be too tired to figure this out.

I have tried this code as suggested but get an empty result.

```
<?php
$records = 
Array
(
    [attribute_id] => 6703
    [base_product] => 382
    )
Array
(
    [attribute_id] => 6704
    [base_product] => 397
)
Array
(
    [attribute_id] => 6705
    [base_product] => 409    
)
Array
(
    [attribute_id] => 6706
    [base_product] => 321
);
$attribute_id_val = 6705;
$base_product_val = $records[array_search($attribute_id_val, array_column($records, "attribute_id"))]["base_product"];
print_r ($base_product_val);
?>
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? Does this data format have a name? Do you already have some kind of library for parsing this format?

Comment: I'm assuming this is PHP, but can you *tag* this question with the programing language you're using?

Comment: Use a loop to iterate over all elements, find the element that has the correct `attribute_id`, then return its `base_product`.

Comment: Oops on the missing info. I had considered doing a loop as suggested but would prefer to avoid it because the array has over 250,000 lines.

Comment: I have to ask, why does this array have 250 000 records? Why is it not stored in a database for querying? That and the fact that this has kept your site down for four days does not bode well for the future of your site!

Comment: The data is stored in a mysql database. I know how to get the data into an array. Searching that array and getting the relevant data is the issue. It's not an option to just do a mysql query.I hosting provider has limit on queries per hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$base_product_val = $records[array_search($attribute_id_val, array_column($records, "attribute_id"))]["base_product"];
?>
```

[`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function is new in PHP 5.5 and returns all the values from a single column in a multidimensional array. Quite handy.

Works great for me:

```
mike ~ $ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $records = [["attribute_id"=>6703, "base_product"=>382], ["attribute_id"=>6704, "base_product"=>397], ["attribute_id"=>6705, "base_product"=>409]];
php > $attribute_id_val = 6705;
php > $base_product_val = $records[array_search($attribute_id_val, array_column($records, "attribute_id"))]["base_product"];
php > echo $base_product_val;
409
php > exit
mike ~ $
```

Comment: I tried this and some other similar code but only get empty results. Not sure if it's just me or what. I added the full code to the original question.

Comment: Sorry, small typo is fixed now.

Comment: I found the problem. One of my array names was spelled wrong. Thanks @miken32 for the great suggestion.